# Fallback repository for BuildBot

Tags: git, buildbot

I have two machines serving a certain git repo, kept in sync.
I would like to configure BuildBot so that the Git pull steps tries both repositories, so that one could go down without disturbing builds (which are initiated through a nightly scheduler, so I don't care about change source to detect repository changes).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way at the moment to achieve this. You will be on your own.

You could think of subclassing self.runCommand here:

https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/blob/master/master/buildbot/steps/source/git.py#L381

so that it first try with the normal repo and then try again after doing insteadOf trick:
https://mraw.org/blog/2011/05/24/Git_tip_of_the_day_insteadOf/